# Change citation style in Ckeditor

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ckeditor

I would like to change the citation style in Ckeditor when we click on the button in the editor.
I would like that when we click on this button it creates the following code :

```
<div class="blockquote-guillemets">
        My text
</div>
```

Have you an idea ?

Comment: Did you try to define your own style for this class?

Comment: Yes i've a style which works for this class. I want assign this class to the citation button of the ckeditor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ckeditor citation button already have specific class `cke_button__blockquote`

Use this class to assign your style to it

```
.cke_button__blockquote {
   // ...
}
```

Comment: You an define this style in your stylesheet file and it should override existed styles

Comment: When I click on the citation button it creates `<blockquotes></blockquotes>` and not `class="cke_button__blockquote"`